# Python Tkinter ttk calendar

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkcalendar

I am trying to create a drop down calendar for a date entry.
Below is a portion of my code:

The drop down portion of it dosen't work and I can't seem to find the syntax for `DateEntry()` of ttk calendar anywhere to include the calendar widget option!

```
#creating the frame 
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

root = Tk()

f1=Frame(root,width=1500,height=100,relief=SUNKEN,bd=4,bg='light steel blue')
f1.pack(side=TOP)
f2=Frame(root,width=1500,height=550,relief=SUNKEN,bd=4,bg='white')
f2.pack()
f3=Frame(root,width=1600,height=100,relief=SUNKEN,bd=4,bg='white')
f3.pack(side=BOTTOM)


#Creating the date column
l4=Label(f2,text='DATE',font=('tahoma',20,'bold'),fg='black',anchor='w')
l4.grid(row=0,column=3)

cal=DateEntry(f2,dateformat=3,width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=4,Calendar =2018)
cal.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='nsew')
```

I want it to look like this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is a problem with the code you provide, you are using `root` (in `f1=..` before defining it)

Comment: In addition, I don't understand what you want to achieve exactly. Are you talking about https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar?

Comment: @j_4321 apologies manual error . My issue is , i am trying to create a calendar dropdown where once the user clicks it ,there is a small calendar drop down and he is able to select the date ; The selected date then appears in the space.My issue is with this line of code   
           cal=DateEntry(f2,dateformat=3,width=12, background='darkblue',
                        foreground='white', borderwidth=4,Calendar =2018)

Comment: concerning syntax, check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tkcalendar#Documentation

Comment: `DateEntry` has no keyword `Calendar`, just directly pass the calendar keywords.

Comment: @j_4321yes ive viewed the page ,not sure how i go about doing this "just directly pass the calendar keywords"

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what option you want to pass to the widget?

Comment: i want it to look like this  :https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/excel-calendar/dropdown-calendar-excel.png @j_4321 my comment merely fetches the current date but i cant seem to get the calendar to appear below it

Comment: "directly" means you can use the same keywords as in Calendar - ie. `Calendar( ..., year=2018)` and  `DateEntry( ... year=2018)`

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. Except for the line displaying today's date, `DateEntry` gives a result very similar to the one in the picture, the calendar appears when the user clicks on the arrow button.

Comment: @j_4321 exactly thats where the problem is the arrow is not clickable

Comment: @furas yep tries it like cal5=DateEntry(f2,dateformat=3,width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=4) ; problem is the drop down isnt actionable

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: I have fixed the issue and published a new version of [tkcalendar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tkcalendar).

**EDIT**: the problem is that in Windows, the drop-down does not open when the downarrow button is clicked. It seems that  it comes from the default ttk theme for Windows because it works with other themes. So the workaround is to switch theme and use 'clam' for instance ('alt' should work as well). Meanwhile, I will look into it and see if I can fix the `DateEntry` for the other themes and release a new version (https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/3).

I am not sure what you want to achieve exactly with the `DateEntry`, but if your goal is to make it look like the one in the picture, it can be done the following way:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import date

root = tk.Tk()
# change ttk theme to 'clam' to fix issue with downarrow button
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')

class MyDateEntry(DateEntry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        DateEntry.__init__(self, master=None, **kw)
        # add black border around drop-down calendar
        self._top_cal.configure(bg='black', bd=1)
        # add label displaying today's date below
        tk.Label(self._top_cal, bg='gray90', anchor='w',
                 text='Today: %s' % date.today().strftime('%x')).pack(fill='x')

# create the entry and configure the calendar colors
de = MyDateEntry(root, year=2016, month=9, day=6,
                 selectbackground='gray80',
                 selectforeground='black',
                 normalbackground='white',
                 normalforeground='black',
                 background='gray90',
                 foreground='black',
                 bordercolor='gray90',
                 othermonthforeground='gray50',
                 othermonthbackground='white',
                 othermonthweforeground='gray50',
                 othermonthwebackground='white',
                 weekendbackground='white',
                 weekendforeground='black',
                 headersbackground='white',
                 headersforeground='gray70')
de.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I created a class inheriting from `DateEntry` to add the label with today's date below the calendar and to create a black border around the drop-down (`self._top_cal` is the `Toplevel` containing the calendar).

Then, I created an instance of `MyDateEntry` and with all calendar options needed to make it look like the picture. In addition, I used the `year`, `month`, `day` options to define the initial date inside the entry.
Here is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So Ive compiled the code and all i'm getting is a date entry box with the drop down unactionable . Am i missing something here ? is there a bug in python 3.4.0 ?? not sure what the prob is :(

Comment: @user9093127 I am using python 3.6 and tcl/tk 8.6, so this might be a compatibility issue. I am using appveyor and travis-ci to check the compatibility for older python (including python 3.4) but I don't remember if I have written a test for the button. What OS are you using and with which version of tk?

Comment: m using python 3.4.0 and tk8.6 ;windows os

Comment: I have tested the `DateEntry` with python 3.3.7 and 3.4.7 in linux and it works. I don't have windows available right now, but I will make some tests when I can.

Comment: @user9093127 I think I have identified the issue, it is Windows default ttk theme which is less flexible than others and does not seems to handle the downarrow button right. So for now, the solution is to change theme (I have updated the answer) and I will see if I can fix the problem with Windows theme.

Comment: @user9093127 I have fixed the issue on WIndows  and published a new release.

Comment: @j_4321 : tkcalendar, DateEntry is not working for me. On trying to install it using pip install tkcalendar its throwing an error ("No matching distribution found for tkcalendar")

Comment: @GarimaTiwari which OS and python version are you using?

Comment: @j_4321 : I am using Python 3.6.1 on Windows7

Comment: @GarimaTiwari I don't have access to Windows to test it right now but pip works for me with python3.6 on Linux. Please open a bug report on https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @j_4321 : I was able to install tkcalendar finally! there seemed to be some restriction in terms of the packages we could download earlier.

Comment: @j_4321 : I do however have another question in relation to DateEntry please - can you have a look at this please? Many many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625818/how-to-get-the-selected-date-for-dateentry-in-tkcalendar-python