# How to get the selected date for DateEntry in tkcalendar (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have a tkcalendar and it's pre-defined widget for Calendar, DateEntry and am trying to get the **User's selected date for DateEntry.**
Whereas there is provision to extract the selected date for the Calendar widget using *"selection_get()"* but nothing for DateEntry that I could find.

I have tried get_date(),get(),_date(), cget(), ._selection() amongst many others but they don't seem to return/print the user-selected date.
Please help, kindly let me know if any added information is needed

Code [picked from a simple tkcalendar tutorial]:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def calendar_view():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2018, month=2, day=5)
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

def dateentry_view():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    print(cal.cget(DateEntry))

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')

ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar', command=calendar_view()).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='DateEntry', command=dateentry_view()).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mention you have tried `get_date()` and it didn't work, but that's actually the right function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def calendar_view():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14", selectmode='day',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2018, month=2, day=5)
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

def dateentry_view():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.get_date())
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')

ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar', command=calendar_view).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='DateEntry', command=dateentry_view).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to get the date every time it is changed you can use an event binding. From [the documentation](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar#documentation):

> - Virtual Events
>
> > A `<<CalendarSelected>>` event is generated each time the user selects a day with the mouse.

So you can bind the function that gets the date to the `<<CalendarSelected>>` event:

```
def dateentry_view():
    def print_sel(e):
        print(cal.get_date())
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    cal.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", print_sel)
```

Comment: I was trying to print the date using cal.get_date() but right after the cal.pack(...) command since I want to be able to get the user selected date as soon as he is selecting it. Any thoughts on why it doesn't happen without passing it via a button?

Comment: This link is in fact where I got the basic code from - missed the event binding point though. Wish I could double-upvote you for the under 15 minutes response+ resolution. Thank YOU! :)

Comment: @GarimaTiwari I did the double for you :)